# Catch Warning message of operator

Tags: python, scripting

When the bind button is clicked, it will display some message in the UI

[image]

I'm trying to store a message as a global variable while handling that operation through the API.

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_add()
cube.modifiers.new("", "LAPLACIANDEFORM")
md = cube.modifiers.active
md.vertex_group = "Group"

s = ""
try:
    with bpy.context.temp_override(object=cube):
        bpy.ops.object.laplaciandeform_bind(modifier=cube.modifiers.active.name)
except Warning as ex:
    print("success, store the message")
    s = str(ex)
```

It failed.
It shows up on the console but didn't catch it.